# AppEngine: go runtime limitations

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm an avid GAE/J user, now trying to create my first GAE/go project.

What are the limitations of the AppEngine Go runtime compared to Java or Python runtimes? Missing APIs? Runtime limitations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/features/ covers what features are implemented by which runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

What I was able to find out so far is:

1. DB Query: missing [composite filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query.CompositeFilter) (`AND` and `OR`).
2. DB Query: missing "member of" [filter operator](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Filters) (`IN`).
3. No [App Identity API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/) **Edit**: this seems to [exist](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference), but is not listed under services
4. No [Prospective Search](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/prospectivesearch/)